# How to make a JScrollBar only scroll vertically?

Tags: java, swing, interface

is there a way to make scroll bars in Java only scroll in a certain direction? Look at this example I made:

```
public class Main
  extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
    public Main ()
    {
        initComponents ();
        this.setSize ( 1000, 1000);
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings ("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents()
    {
        java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jSplitPane1 = new javax.swing.JSplitPane();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0));
        setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 1000));
        setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 1000));
        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        jLabel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("sansserif", 0, 36)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("<html>Scroll Test</html>");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(10, 0, 10, 0);
        jPanel1.add(jLabel1, gridBagConstraints);

        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        getContentPane().add(jPanel1, gridBagConstraints);

        jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jPanel2.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        jSplitPane1.setDividerLocation(-1);
        jSplitPane1.setResizeWeight(0.5);
        jSplitPane1.setToolTipText("");

        jPanel3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jPanel3.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("sansserif", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jLabel3.setText("<html>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla a est condimentum, dignissim felis nec, egestas orci. Proin in lectus blandit, congue odio sed, semper leo. Nulla dolor ex, tincidunt et ullamcorper in, facilisis sollicitudin ligula. Nam luctus mollis libero nec suscipit. Morbi rutrum sollicitudin nunc non interdum. Mauris augue risus, maximus et eros at, commodo egestas leo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nullam pulvinar non velit vitae vehicula. Nullam quis magna sed odio tempor pulvinar sed nec dolor. Nunc ut vulputate massa. Donec faucibus, diam vitae pharetra tempus, diam leo pretium nulla, sit amet egestas orci felis et mauris. Proin rhoncus diam eget rhoncus malesuada. Pellentesque a lacus id eros interdum interdum.</html>");
        jLabel3.setVerticalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.TOP);
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        jPanel3.add(jLabel3, gridBagConstraints);

        jSplitPane1.setLeftComponent(jPanel3);

        jScrollPane1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        jPanel4.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jPanel4.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        jLabel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("sansserif", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jLabel2.setText("<html>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla a est condimentum, dignissim felis nec, egestas orci. Proin in lectus blandit, congue odio sed, semper leo. Nulla dolor ex, tincidunt et ullamcorper in, facilisis sollicitudin ligula. Nam luctus mollis libero nec suscipit. Morbi rutrum sollicitudin nunc non interdum. Mauris augue risus, maximus et eros at, commodo egestas leo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nullam pulvinar non velit vitae vehicula. Nullam quis magna sed odio tempor pulvinar sed nec dolor. Nunc ut vulputate massa. Donec faucibus, diam vitae pharetra tempus, diam leo pretium nulla, sit amet egestas orci felis et mauris. Proin rhoncus diam eget rhoncus malesuada. Pellentesque a lacus id eros interdum interdum.</html>");
        jLabel2.setVerticalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.TOP);
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        jPanel4.add(jLabel2, gridBagConstraints);

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jPanel4);

        jSplitPane1.setRightComponent(jScrollPane1);

        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
        jPanel2.add(jSplitPane1, gridBagConstraints);

        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
        getContentPane().add(jPanel2, gridBagConstraints);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try
        {
            for ( javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels () )
            {
                if ( "Nimbus".equals ( info.getName () ) )
                {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel ( info.getClassName () );
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch ( ClassNotFoundException ex )
        {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger ( Main.class.getName () ).log ( java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex );
        }
        catch ( InstantiationException ex )
        {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger ( Main.class.getName () ).log ( java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex );
        }
        catch ( IllegalAccessException ex )
        {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger ( Main.class.getName () ).log ( java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex );
        }
        catch ( javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex )
        {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger ( Main.class.getName () ).log ( java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex );
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater ( new Runnable ()
        {
            public void run ()
            {
                new Main ().setVisible ( true );
            }

        } );
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JSplitPane jSplitPane1;
    // End of variables declaration
```

If you take a look to the left container, you'll see that text automatically goes down when it reachs the container's end. I want the same to happen with the right scroll bar.
I believe a possible solution would be tolock the width of the container that's inside the scroll pane to be always the same as the scrollpane's width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a JLabel to display the text you can use a `JTextArea` and turn wrapping on. A `JTextarea` implements the `Scrollable` interface which will allow the text to wrap when the width of the scroll pane is reached

> I believe a possible solution would be to lock the width of the container that's inside the scroll pane to be always the same as the scrollpane's width.

Or you can use a custom component that implements the `Scrollable` interface. Then you can tell the component width to be equal to the scroll pane width.

An easy way to do this is to use the [Scrollable Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/12/20/scrollable-panel/). It will allow you to configure the panel to fit in the width of the scroll pane:

```
ScrollablePanel panel = new ScrollablePanel( new BorderLay );
panel.setScrollableWidth( ScrollablePanel.ScrollableSizeHint.FIT );
```

Then you add the label to the panel and the panel to the scroll pane.

Comment: Yes, using a text area is way more easier and faster. Thanks.